# Convert date to BST java

Tags: java, date, format

I need to convert the date from **2021-08-21T17:36:51.000+00:00** to **2021-08-21 06:36 PM BST(+1)** using java
any help

Comment: If the date is not in the summer time (DST) part of the year, which result do you want then?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far in order to find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`OffsetDateTime#withOffsetSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#withOffsetSameInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-) to meet this requirement.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime source = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-08-21T17:36:51.000+00:00");
        OffsetDateTime target = source.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+01:00"));
        System.out.println(target);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd hh:mm a O", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = dtf.format(target);
        System.out.println(formatted);

        // Replace GMT with BST to get the required string
        formatted = formatted.replaceFirst("GMT([+\\-]\\d+)", "BST($1)");
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-08-21T18:36:51+01:00
2021-08-21 06:36 PM GMT+1
2021-08-21 06:36 PM BST(+1)
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/vpMT4J)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: I need the output date to be  2021-08-21 06:36 PM BST(+1)  not 2021-08-21T18:36:51+01:00

Comment: @DavidIshak -  BST (British Summer Time) is not a standard timezone name. Anyway, I've posted a solution to meet your specific requirement.